# Missing getFrame method in Jcodec 0.1.9 in Android

Tags: android, jcodec

I'm using [Jcodec](http://jcodec.org/) for my application..

I've added this in my gradle:

```
compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec:0.1.9'
```

However when I tried to follow the example on that page, Android Studio cannot resolve getFrame() method. When I tried to look at code, there's no such method at all. Instead there's getNativeFrame.

```
int frameNumber = 150;
BufferedImage frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("filename.mp4"), frameNumber);
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
```

But from what I've seen in most sample here in stackoverflow, they are using getFrame.

What could possibly went wrong?
Am I missing some component here? Is the gradle dependency incorrect? How do you setup Jcodec for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the plain old JCodec. There's is an Android specific version at the bottom of [this](http://jcodec.org/) page. At the time of writing this answer, the version number is 0.1.7 and there is no Maven repo that I can find.

Comment: ah i see. so basically, I dont have any other option but to import the project itself to my own project. anyways thank you for the answer.

Comment: @kishidp Yup. I'm afraid that that's what I had to resort to doing.